# Qt installer framework: translating config.xml attributes

Tags: xml, qt, translation, qt-installer

You can translate attributes of package.xml like:

```
    <Description>Miam-Player is the main program. It is required and cannot be 
    unselected.</Description>
    <Description xml:lang="fr_fr">Miam-Player est le programme principal. Il 
    est requis et ne peut être désélectionné.</Description>
```

but this does not work with config.xml

How do you translate attributes of config.xml such as 'Name', 'Title' etc. ?